# Unable to call generic Url.Action<TController> method from View

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mvccontrib

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 3, along with MvcContrib v 3.  MvcContrib has a UrlHelper extension that I'm trying to use in my view.  The extension code is as follows:

```
public static class UrlHelperExtensions
{
    public static string Action<TController>(this UrlHelper urlHelper, Expression<Action<TController>> expression)
    where TController : Controller
    {
        return LinkBuilder.BuildUrlFromExpression<TController>(urlHelper.RequestContext, urlHelper.RouteCollection, expression);
    }
}
```

However, ASP.NET MVC does not appear to like any syntax I try when using the method in my View.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Surround it with a `@()`. You can't use generics in Razor outside a `@()` block.
It would be like:

```
@(Url.Action<TController>(c => c.YourAction())
```